# Installing lua5.2 vs. lua5.3 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, lua

When I install the `lua5.2` package on Ubuntu 16.10:

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.2
```

it installs `/usr/bin/lua` as a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/lua-interpreter`, which in turn is a symlink to `/usr/bin/lua5.2.

When I install the `lua-5.3` package, it doesn't create the symlinks; I only get `/usr/bin/lua5.3`.

The output of `dkg -L lua5.X`, which lists the files owned by the package, is identical (aside from version numbers on some files) for the `lua5.2` and `lua5.3` packages.

What I want to do is just install the latest and greatest version of Lua, which is currently 5.3, and be able to use `#!/usr/bin/lua` in scripts.

I know I can work around this by creating the symlinks manually or by using the `update-alternatives` command (which I haven't yet figured out, but that's not what I'm asking about).

My question is, why does the `lua5.3` package *not* set up the `/usr/bin/lua` symlink when I install it, while the `lua5.2` package does? Is this deliberate, perhaps an Ubuntu policy, or is it just an oversight by the people who created the package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the package maintainer didn't provide the `alternatives` infrastructure. Unfortunately no way around it but to set it up manually or just plain symlink `/usr/bin/lua` to `/usr/bin/lua5.3`.

I've submitted a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lua5.3/+bug/1707212

Answer (score 15):

This is still an issue in 18.04 Bionic. Workaround:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/lua lua-interpreter \
/usr/bin/lua5.3 130 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/lua.1.gz \
lua-manual /usr/share/man/man1/lua5.3.1.gz

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/luac lua-compiler \
/usr/bin/luac5.3 130 --slave /usr/share/man/man1/luac.1.gz \
lua-compiler-manual /usr/share/man/man1/luac5.3.1.gz
```

Comment: Thanks. Your workaround also works on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.